# Maintenance contract as a Full-Stack developer with big company

Tags: contracts, freelance-websites, web-development, maintenance

I know the question have been debated here, but I didn't quite find a lot of informations about developement (most was about CMS aka WordPress, Drupal)

So I did a mission of about 3 months with a big company (~65000 employees). The mission was about adding the missing features and debugging as Full-Stack (Laravel Backend, JQuery/HTML/CSS Front) of an internal reference database they use daily

Now they liked my work, they want a maintenance contract for this needs :

```
- maintenance of the server (adding a little bit of DevOps there)
- potential debugging of the application
- potential evolution of the application
```

And the contract should be an annual one

As I'm a bit starting of with big company as a freelancer, I don't know how I could price my maintenance contract.
As a first try, I made one that charge an annual fee for the disponibility it imply accompagned with an ascending hour payments for each degree of maintenance they would (is the need impterative ? critical ? or simply a need of little debugging ?) but I don't know if it could fit as big company there tends to like all-in-one annual fees and basta.

So how could you see a good round up of this and maybe give a poential price ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about offer them a fixed price for one year of maintenance with an hour-cap.

Like, this agreement shall include up to 96 work-hours per year. Work exceeding that amount will be charged at a rate of xy. Unused hours will be discarded ate the end of the year and may not be redistributed to other tasks...
(*Adjust to your need and have wording checked by lawyer*)

Then be sure to keep track of your hours and share with them on a monthly basis. Also you should define how hours are counted, like every request is rounded up to to at least 15 minutes.

Also be sure to leave you enough room for your response time - you my be sick or on holidays so guaranteeing a 24 hour reaction time under all circumstances may not be the feasible.

Comment: The hour-cap is a good idea ! Thanx for it. Can you think of a reasonable price I could set in this situation ? Knowing that they paid me 40€/h during the mission and now I understand their needs and the techs, I can ask for a bit more.

Comment: I really don´t know what is appropriate in your area and field. I always found that such an arrangement should get a discount from my base-rate, as it is pre-sold. You have no acquisition costs and it is nice to have some fixed income, maybe the´ll not even use up the hours. On the other hand, you can steer you customer with your pricing, so this ultimately depends on where you want to go with this.